# UWP List View Overflow with large List

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use a ListView in a UWP app to display some tabular data. I am able to produce the table just fine, however, when binding the ListView to a collection greater than about 50,000 items or so, the ListView items overflow the bounds of the listview itself, which can be seen by applying a border to the listview as demonstrated in the attached picture.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?
[Listview Items Overflowing Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcB79.png)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15.8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
            <ListView x:Name="CartGrid" SelectionMode="Extended" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="2">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="12" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="408"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="First Name" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Surname" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Category" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="TableDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:Person">
                        <Grid Height="48" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Firstname}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Firstname}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Lastname}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Category}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please post you XAML code

Comment: This behavior really happens only with more than 50000 items?

Comment: Yeah, if i change it to like 40,000 or so there is no over flow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug in UWP and it has been reported but not fixed yet (see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52049/uwp-listview-viewport-overflow.html)).

I think there is a solution that could theoretically fix this: using `Clip` to clip the visible are of the `ListView`:

```
<ListView Width="300" Height="200">
   <ListView.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Width="300" Height="200" />
   </ListView.Clip>
</ListView>
```

But this would cause another problem - the last items could never be displayed as they would overflow and be clipped. You could solve this by adding "fake" empty items to the list, but of course this is very suboptimal solution. It would be better if the API was fixed itself.

Comment: It looks like in that link, they just directed the asker to the msdn site as the issue wasnt with VS and this was posted about a year ago. I couldn't find any active questions on that site and I had had trouble finding any results from googling at all or even people suffering from the same issues. I guess because the listview isn't designed for what it was back in winforms (which is what i am trying to loosely achieve) this issue may not be widely known, so I guess I will post on MSDN and see what they come back with. Good to know that its not just me going crazy though...

Comment: You could try the `DataGrid` control in the Telerik UWP Toolkit, which might match your needs better. However, it will be great if you report the bug on MSDN forums so that the Dev Team knows about it

Comment: I was inititally using that control from Telerik as it was better suited, however it suffered from the same issue, which i thought was isolated to that control. Which is why I started searching for alternative methods and discovered it occurs with a standard listview aswell. The telerik control also appears to have no "Extended" Selection mode (Ctrl and Shift click selecting) that I could establish, which would otherwise have made it a great alternative, had it not overflowed the container aswell.

Comment: That is pretty bad then... I think it should be escalated. I will probably make a Github repro and try to post it to some people in Microsoft. Once you write on MSDN, could you send me a link please?

Comment: Yeah something odd is going on indeed, i couldnt post pictures or links on there but here is my open question on MSDN with my XAML and the issue explained.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74683608-763a-423a-b44f-2327fbec8744/uwp-listview-item-overflowing-container-bounds?forum=wpdevelop